# laravel custom view directory service provider

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, service-provider

why am I getting this error: **"View [index] not found."**

I use custom view directory

**Controller**

```
public function index()
    {
        return view('categories::index');
    }
```

**ServiceProvider**

```
class CategoryServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    public function boot()
    {
        $this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__.'../Views', 'categories');
    }
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind(CategoryRepositoryInterface::class, CategoryRepository::class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not it?

```
public function index()
{
    return view('categories.index');
}
```